# Errors In Theme Design Options

Tags: error, troubleshooting

I attempted to upgrade a theme I had installed in the past.  When the upgrade failed (for whatever reason) I reverted back to a backup.  Though outwardly the site looks fine, when I go into the design options for the theme (Theme Name > Theme Options v1.6 > Design Options), I get these errors:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/local:/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/community:/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/core:/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 244

Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/local:/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/community:/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/core:/home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /home/be2ue8tp/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php on line 108
```

I spoke to the developers of the theme and they claim it's magento errors and not their theme. I'm fairly new with Magento so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This error sounds like your `app/code/Mage.php` is missing. This errors are not helpful. Please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store to learn how to give better error explanation.

Comment: Yes @Fabian, I can see that the file is missing but I don't know where I would find it.  I checked the theme folder (an updated one) and in a new downloaded version of magento...and I don't see a Mage.php file in either one.

Answer (score 1):

This error sounds like your `app/Mage.php` is missing. This errors are not helpful.

This file is part of Magento core, so you can just download the right version from magento.com and copy it from there.

But when you lost this file, I wouldn't be sure that there are more files missing.

Comment: I had tried downloading a fresh version of Magento, both 1.8.1.0 and 1.9.0.1 and I get the same error.  I checked even those folders and the file isn't there, so of course, the error stays.

Comment: Corrected the post. the path was wrong. `Mage.php` lives in `app/`